# upgradable digest / checksum algorithm

Tags: algorithm, hash, checksum

I would like to create a database containing checksums of a lot of files and I fear for checksum-collissions (two different files with the same checksum).

Question 1: what is the probability two different files will have the same MD5 sum?

As a workaround I thought about using an increasing checksum. Start with a small checksum and, in case of a collision calculate a larger checksum which can be derived to the smaller checksum  so I don't have to recalculate the checksums of all my files already in the database... I still want to be able to search for a smaller sized checksums.

Question 2: which checksum / digest algorithm could do this trick? I need a checksum algorithm which can calculate a value of a certain size and "backwards" compatible (of a smaller size). Ie. file1 has a 2 byte checksum of 0x1234 and a 4 byte checksum of 0x12345678, the 2 byte checksum can be derived from the 4 byte checksum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1: depends how many files you have. For each pair, it is approximately 1 in 2^128. If you have 2^64 files (which I reckon you probably don't), the probability of at least one collision among them is about 0.5.

This assumes no malice on the part of whoever produces the files. There are known MD5 collisions, and known ways to generate files that collide. If someone can make money at your expense by exposing you to collisions, then the probability of a collision is close to 1 :-)

Question 2: normally you'd just use a better hash to begin with (perhaps SHA-256) and then your "small" hash is either the first few bytes of the large one, or the first one taken modulo some large number, perhaps a prime. But it depends what you want it for.

A cheap and cheerful option would be for the "large" hash to be two or more "small" hashes concatenated together - hash the file forwards and backwards, for example. Of course once the small hash is broken, there's no telling whether or not that break will lead to a break of the combination of two+ hashes.

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer but I'm not sure if it answers my question completely yet. Are you sure about the chance of .5 with 2^64 files even with the "birthday paradox"? What would be the chance of a duplicate with SHA-256?

Comment: @meeuw: It's not exactly 0.5 for 2^64, but there is a number of files somewhere around the order of 2^64, for which it is 0.5. Since SHA-256 is a 256-bit hash, you would need something in the order of 2^128 files with uniformly-distributed hashes before you get a 0.5 chance of at least one collision.

Answer (score 0):

Google for "birthday paradox", and be content to know that the numbers are unmanageably huge.  The probability of a collision increases rather quickly, but for something like a SHA or MD, it doesn't make much of a dent in the original probability for the first two.

BTW, if this is for a cryptographic purpose, MD5 is deprecated.  If you're just deduplicating or something, MD5 should be fine.